# Change value in a collection using local variable

Tags: java, collections

My question is, using Java is it possible to have a collection such as a tree. Have a node in the tree saved to a variable. It would be the same object address wise(in my understanding) so does that mean changing the data in the node using the local variable would also change the data in the collection?

Comment: Why don't you just test it? But yes, if you have two references to the same object, changing the state of the unique object using one reference will change it, and the other reference will still point to the same, modified object.

Answer (score 0):

The local variable holds a reference to the node, so changing data in your local variable will indeed change the data in the object it references, in this case the node in your tree will also be changed because it is the same object.

Best regards

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The answer is kinda. Assuming you have variable `var` and it's address is stored in collection `things`. Then if you do something like: `var = some_var` , the data in the collection will not change. This is because you are overwriting the address of var in the assignment. However, if you were to modify var somehow, both would change. This happens because the address is staying the same, so you are still writing to the correct memory. e.g. `var.field = some_data` would modify `things[var].field`.

For this reason, it is usually good practice to load a copy of `var` into `things`, by doing this we don't leave them connected accidentally. People often leave things connected like this without realizing, then modify the variable without realizing that the collection has also changed.